# find user disconnection time in RDP session Windows server 2012

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, taskmanager

We have a pool of develop machines where developers log in through RDP and usually they doesn't log off but just disconnect. As local administrator I can force the log off but I would like to check when the user disconnected.

From task manager I can see only the user name and its status

[image]

Is there a way to discover when the user disconnected using task manager, powershell, cmd or whatever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know this is not in the security logs. The correct place to look for is in `Microsoft Event Viewer` under `Applications and Services Logs => Microsoft => Windows => TerminalServices-LocalSessionManager => Operational` and then under the Operational logs.

The eventID to look for is ID24 (disconnected user session). EventID 25 is a reconnect.

Comment: perfect, thank you! I corrected the path, it was incomplete. In that view I can find only real user connection, exactly what I was looking for

Answer (score 13):

You can use windows command **query user *UserName* /server:*ServerName*** or you can just enter **query user /server:*ServerName*** to find out all active or disconnected sessions.

Below is the sample output, I have blurred out my info for privacy:

[image]

I have also created a PowerShell script to do this task automatically, here is the link [Powershell to find out disconnected RDP session and log off at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352905/powershell-to-find-out-disconnected-rdp-session-and-log-off-at-the-same-time)

Comment: This is nice, but it appears some copies of Windows have the RPC service disabled by default.

Comment: @tresf this is from 2017 so may not be relevant anymore

Comment: It's still the most upvoted, so it's meant as no slight against the solution, but rather a warning for others.  Meanwhile -- albeit a lot more code -- I found [this solution](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/306mcn/wtsenumeratesessions/.) on reddit which works without RPC available.  I've made a minimal example of this [here](https://gist.github.com/tresf/b0d3d06728236fe988384a8e14c0d019) tested on Windows 11. Unfortunately, the solution does not have the username, which is critical for what I was looking for.  In the end, I used another solution entirely, but wanted to share. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can start the Windows Event Viewer and check under `Windows logs --> Security`. Filter by `'Task Category = Logoff'`.

You can export it to xml for easier reading.

[image]

Comment: Why don't you edit your previous answer and include this, instead of posting two answers (which are the same)?

Comment: ok answer nearly correct, of course I can't find the logoff because he didn't logged off, but just disconnected. Anyway I can't find any details, my security logs history is just too short

Comment: a Logoff is something completely different as a disconnect in RDP.

Answer (score 0):

Start-->Run-->Eventvwr-->Windows logs-->Security. Filter by 'Task Category = Logoff'