# Powershell to find out disconnected RDP session and log off at the same time

Tags: powershell, logout, rdp, windows-server, disconnected-session

Is there a script that can log out my disconnected RDP session from any server? This is causing a lot of pain and constant ad account lockouts.

Any help would be awesome.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have got the answer and I am writing this answer to help someone in need as I had to figure this out myself. I created a script using online resources to find out disconnected RDP sessions on all Windows Server in my AD environment. I run a query on each Windows Server and create a CSV formatted list, I then use that list to log out my ID from those servers, so I don't have any disconnected sessions.

I did this to make sure my AD account doesn't get locked out due to some disconnected RDP sessions when its time to change my password.

You are free to modify this script as per your need.

**Script Code is below:**

```
param (
        #get current logged on username
        [string]$UserName = $env:USERNAME
    )

    # Import the Active Directory module for the Get-ADComputer CmdLet
    Import-Module ActiveDirectory


    # Query Active Directory for enabled windows servers computer accounts and sort by name
    $Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter {(OperatingSystem -like "*windows*server*") -and (Enabled -eq "True")} | Sort Name

    # Initiating variables
    $SessionList = $NULL
    $queryResults = $NULL
    $SError = $null
    $SDown = $null
    $z = 0

    # Get total number of servers
    $count = $Servers.count 


    # Start looping through each server at a time
    ForEach ($Server in $Servers) {    

        # initiate counter for showing progress
        $z = $z + 1

        $ServerName = $Server.Name

        # Start writing progress 
        Write-Progress -Activity "Processing Server: $z out of $count servers." -Status " Progress" -PercentComplete ($z/$Servers.count*100)

        # check if server is pingable before running the query on the server
        if (Test-Connection $Server.Name -Count 1 -Quiet) {  

            Write-Host "`n`n$ServerName is online!" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black

            Write-Host ("`nQuerying Server: `"$ServerName`" for disconnected sessions under UserName: `"" + $UserName.ToUpper() + "`"...") -BackgroundColor Gray -ForegroundColor Black

            # Store results in array
            [array]$queryResults += (

                # Query server for specific username
                query user $UserName /server:$ServerName | 
                foreach {
                    # Look for lines with Disc string to filter out active sessions
                    if ($_ -match "Disc") {

                        # format the output in CSV by replacing more than 2 spaces with a comman
                        write-output ("`n$ServerName," + (($_.trim() -replace ' {2,}', ',')))
                    }
                }
            )
        }
        # If server is not pingable show error message
        else {
            # Make list of server that are down.
            [array]$SDown += ($ServerName)
            Write-Host "`nError: Unable to connect to $ServerName!" -BackgroundColor red -ForegroundColor white
            Write-Host "Either the $ServerName is down or check for firewall settings on server $ServerName!" -BackgroundColor Yellow -ForegroundColor black
        }
    }

    # If there are some non pingable server then display the list
    if ($SDown -ne $null -and $SDown) {
            Write-Host "`nScript was unable to connect to the following server:" -ForegroundColor White -BackgroundColor Red
            $SDown
    }

    # Check if any disconnected session are stored in the array
    if ($queryResults -ne $null -and $queryResults) {

        # Convert the CSV fromat to table format with headers
        $QueryResultsCSV = $queryResults | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter "," -Header "ServerName","UserName","SessionID","CurrentState","IdealTime","LogonTime"

        # Show the results on console
        $QueryResultsCSV |ft -AutoSize

        # Go through each Disconnected session stored in the array
        $QueryResultsCSV | foreach {

            # Grabb session ID and ServerName
            $Sessionl = $_.SessionID
            $Serverl = $_.ServerName

            # Show message on the console
            Write-Host "`nLogging off"$_.username"from $serverl..." -ForegroundColor black -BackgroundColor Gray
            sleep 2

            # Logout user using session ID
            logoff $Sessionl /server:$Serverl /v

        }
    }
    else {
        # if array is empty display message that no session were found
        Write-Host `n`n`n`n("*" * $LineSize)
        Write-Host "You are all good! No ghost sessions found!" -BackgroundColor Green -ForegroundColor Black
        Write-Host ("*" * $LineSize)
    }

    # Pause at the end so you can capture the output
    $null = Read-Host "`n`nScript execution finished, press enter to exit!"
```

Screenshots:

1. When the script is running on through all server, shows you online and offline servers:
   [image: Inital script run]
2. List of servers that Script was unable to connect:
   [image: List of server script was unable to connect]
3. The script lists the servers where it found disconnected RDP sessions.
   [image: Disconnected RDP Sessions]
4. When script start to log your disconnected sessions off and it pauses at the end.
   [image]

Comment: I know stack doesn't like thank you comments, but I wanted to let you know that this script is amazing. It has made my life 1,000,000 times easier. Thank you!

Comment: @Bridger Happy to help. :)

Comment: Well written, PSTerminalServices is a little more PowerShell native

https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PSTerminalServices/1.0

Comment: @Nixphoe, if i am not mistaken I think i wrote my script 2 years before the PSTerminalServices came out.

Comment: How can I get this to not search for me but another user? Every time I replace $username with the name I'm searching for, it still adds my username into the search

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your sample code. I have created a simplified code to logoff all disconnected users in the same server

```
$hostname = hostname
if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $hostname -Quiet -Count 1){
    $result = query session /server:$hostname
    $rows = $result -split "`n" 
    foreach ($row in $rows) {   
        if ($row -NotMatch "services|console" -and $row -match "Disc") {
            $sessionusername = $row.Substring(19,20).Trim()
            $sessionid = $row.Substring(39,9).Trim()
            Write-Output "Logging Off RDP Disconnected Sessions User $sessionusername"#, $session[2], $session[3]"
            logoff $sessionid /server:$hostname
        }
    }
}
```