# How can I find all RDP sessions disconnected for more than a day

Tags: powershell, server, rdp

I'd like to write a PS script to find any user who has a disconnected RDP session on a server, if it's been disconnected for longer than one day.  Ultimately either email myself the results.  I'm trying to use the `quser` command as that seems to have the info I want, but I can't seem to do anything with those results.  Here is what I have so far.

```
$Servers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=domain,DC=com"

foreach ($Server in $Servers) {
    $Results = (quser /server:$ServerName)
    Write-Host $Results
}
```

Comment: What do you need this for? You could simply configure the Terminal Services to terminate disconnected sessions after a day.

Comment: I have posted the answer to something similar here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43352905/powershell-to-find-out-disconnected-rdp-session-and-log-off-at-the-same-time/43352906#43352906

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just split the results by space and store into array:

```
$parsedresult = $result -split ' +'
```

then the second or the third column would be the state and all the rest I don't remember ;) probably something like 5th column would be time. you can figure it out by looking at the quser output